# PL/SQL - trigger validating data causes that cannot add any row

Tags: oracle, validation, plsql, triggers

I wrote trigger which is checking if the question has question mark. If not, the error is returned. It doesn't work - even if there is question mark, no data is inserted into db. Please help me to resolve this problem.

```
create or replace trigger validate_question
before insert on QUESTIONS
for each row
  declare
    position number(3,0) := -1;
  begin
    select instr(:new.QUESTION_CONTENT,'?') 
    into position 
    FROM QUESTIONS
    where QUESTIONID = :new.QUESTIONID;
    if pozycja = -1 
    then 
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20666, 'This is not a question.');
    end if;
  end;
```

Here is how I call it:

```
set transaction name 'aaa';
insert into QUESTIONS values ('',1,'It should be inserted!?');
commit;
```

Comment: No need for the select, just use `position := instr(:new.QUESTION_CONTENT,'?')` and `instr` returns `0` (zero) if no match is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is correct implementation of the trigger:

```
create or replace trigger validate_question
before insert on questions
for each row
  begin
    if not  instr(:new.question_content,'?') > 0
    then 
      raise_application_error(-20666, 'This is not a question.');

    end if;
  end;
```

However, a better way of enforcing such rules is with a CHECK CONSTRAINT rather than a trigger:

```
SQL> drop trigger  validate_question
  2  /

Trigger dropped.

SQL> alter table questions
  2  add constraint questions_content_ck 
  3  check ( instr(question_content,'?') > 0 )
  4  /

Table altered.

SQL> insert into questions values (1,'Is this a question?');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into questions values (2,'This is not a question');
insert into questions values (2,'This is not a question')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (APC.QUESTIONS_CONTENT_CK) violated


SQL>
```